# "Runaway argument?" just in the \input file

Tags: conditionals, verbatim, etoolbox

**Update:** Upon @egreg suggestion, the case shown below is the core of the problem and has nothing to do with `include/input` statements. I have a `verbatim` within `toggle` statements, which fails. A minimal code for that is

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{tog1}
\toggletrue{tog1}

\begin{document}
    \iftoggle{tog1} {
         \begin{verbatim}
             Hello World!
         \end{verbatim}
    } {
        \textit{Hello World}
    }
\end{document}
```

---

---

**TL;DR** I have toggle cases within which I have a verbatim and this leads to

> "Runaway argument" **Content of verbatim** ! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.

---

I have a peculiar case. I have a latex project with the below directory structure

```
[project_home]
    - main.tex
    - [tex]
        - [folder_1]
            - chapter_1.tex
            - chapter_1_sec_1.tex
        - [folder_2]
            - chapter_2.tex
            - chapter_2_sec_1.tex
    - [img]
        <image files>
```

The `main.tex` file contains include statements to include files from the tex folders (they pertain to the individual chapters).

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\newtoggle{tog1}
\toggletrue{tog1}
..
\begin{document}
    \include{tex/folder_1/chapter_1}
    \include{tex/folder_2/chapter_2}
    ..
\end{document}
```

Within each chapter, I have many sections. I am including these individual section files within the `chapter.tex` and some of these section files have *toggle* statements (etoolbox).

**chapter_1.tex**

```
\chapter{chapter 1}
    \section{section 1}
         \input{chapter_1_sec_1.tex}
         ..
    \section{section 2}
         ..
```

**chapter_1_sec_1.tex**

```
\iftoggle{tog1} {
    \begin{verbatim}
        % some HTML code
    \end{verbatim}
} {
    % The else part
    % No verbatim here, just plain tex text
}
```

Now, with the included `\verbatim` or `\lstlisting` within these toggle cases, the build fails with the above mentioned error.

**Note 1:** The build will not fail if I remove the toggle cases. The `verbatim`/`lstlisting` works just fine when I remove the `toggle` cases and just include the content within the file.

**Note 2:** It will work if I remove the `verbatim`/`lstlisting` sections and have the `toggle` cases.

I tried including the contents of the `chapter_1_sec_1.tex` directly in the `chapter_1.tex` file without the toggle cases. So, there seems to be no problem with nested `include/input` files.

The **ONLY** case when it fails is if I have `verbatim` within `toggles`. I am relatively new to latex and I am not sure if this is an obvious mistake. Could someone point out a correct way/workaround to this problem.
Also, why does this error occur?

Comment: You can't have `verbatim` in the argument to another command. It has nothing to do with `\include`, so you should try and make a self-contained example showing the issue, not relying on included files.

Comment: @egreg So I guess this entire approach is wrong. Is there a way in which I could change this so I get the toggles and some `code-environment`?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible; if nobody comes up with a solution before I've had my dinner, I'll tackle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`verbatim` content is currently being supplied as an argument to `\iftoggle{<toggle>}{<true>}{<false>}` - either in the `<true>` or the `<false>` clause. You can't have `verbatim` content as the argument of a macro as the argument being read fixes the category codes, which `verbatim` wants to change.

One suggestion is to use traditional TeX `\if`s:

```
\newif\iftogA
\togAtrue% Set toggle togA to true
```

and then inside `chapter_1_sec_1.tex`

```
\iftogA
    \begin{verbatim}
        % some HTML code
    \end{verbatim}
\else
    % The else part
    % No verbatim here, just plain TeX text
\fi
```

Here's a minimal example highlighting the use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\iftogA

\begin{document}

\togAtrue% Set toggle togA to true
\iftogA
\begin{verbatim}
Some verbatim text.
\end{verbatim}
\else
Some regular text.
\fi

\togAfalse% Set toggle togA to false
\iftogA
\begin{verbatim}
Some verbatim text.
\end{verbatim}
\else
Some regular text.
\fi

\end{document}
```

---

An issue that is not covered in the question is that of your `verbatim` environment indentation. Note that leading spaces are set as-is under `verbatim` (and [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)), so it's typically advised to avoid that (as I did above).

Comment: Simple and elegant!. `toggle` seems to be the bane of all my problems. My previous question on `Tex SE` also involved 'toggles'. I guess it is time for me to let go of it.

Answer (score 2):

A `verbatim` or `lstlisting` command cannot go in the argument to another command.

You can keep your interface with `\newtoggle` and `\iftoggle`, provided you do something a bit different when `verbatim` or `lstlisting` is involved.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{tog1}

\newcommand{\verbatimtoggle}[1]{%
  TT\fi
  \iftoggle{#1}{\iftrue}{\iffalse}%
}

\begin{document}

\togglefalse{tog1}

\iftoggle{tog1}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\if\verbatimtoggle{tog1}
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim
\end{verbatim}
\fi

\toggletrue{tog1}

\iftoggle{tog1}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\if\verbatimtoggle{tog1}
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim
\end{verbatim}
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use an `\else` branch:

```
\if\verbatimtoggle{tog1}
<true text>
\else
<false text>
\fi
```